# Dividing two numbers always equals zero?

Tags: c#, math, xna, division

In my Xna game, I am trying to have my playfield scale to the screen that it is running on. To do this, I use proportions to find the percent that the real window is scaled relative to my playfield. To do this, I divide the real width by the virtual width:

```
float _percent = _realViewport.Width / this._viewport.Width;
```

I always get 0, though, in the _percent variable. I set up a debug stop point at that line in my code, and analyzed the variables. this._viewport.Width equals 640, and _realViewport.Width equals 1280. So, using my calculator, 640 / 1280 SHOULD equal 0.5, but in my code I always get 0 out, instead of 0.5. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because integer division truncates ([XNA's `Viewport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport_members.aspx) type has integer width and height properties), and 640 / 1280 is 0.5, which truncates to zero.

Cast one of your values to a float if you want floating point division:

```
float _percent = _realViewport.Width / (float)this._viewport.Width;
```

Comment: Right. You'll be using this trick a lot when doing trigonometric calculations.

Answer (score 1):

try this `float _percent = _realViewport.Width * 1.0/ (float)this._viewport.Width;`,by adding multiplication by 1.0, the integer will automatically convert to float.

Comment: This is basically the same as the answer posted before, except you added multiplication by `1.0` for some reason and you didn't explain anything

Comment: @user1306322,I modified the answer, how is this one?

Comment: It's still basically the same thing, and you're doing one extra operation, which is redundant by the way, since any one argument converted to float in this operation would be sufficient. You could have cast both to `(float)` *or* multiplied by `1.0` to the same effect, former of which I personally prefer to do, as the code is more obvious that way.